# "Распахнуть ресницы" — можно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

[**Е. Звёздная. Шепот в темноте**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=67332&p=50):

*1. Остановившись, **распахнула ресницы** и улыбнулась луне.

2. **Распахнув ресницы**, посмотрела в небо и поняла — луна поет!*

Есть устойчивое выражение [**распахнуть глаза**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/139080).
А можно ли распахивать ресницы? Правильно ли **так** говорить?

Answer (score 2):

> — Вы оказываете нам честь. Грета Гарбо медленно распахнула ресницы. 
>    *Ю. М. Нагибин*. Блестящая и горестная жизнь Имре Кальмана.
>
> ... приразинули припухшие рты и распахнули ресницы, прозрачно глядя на
>   царевну. 
>    *А. Н. Толстой*. Петр Первый.

В песенной поэзии, рекламном «творчестве, публицистике есть и такие примеры, как этот:

> Фантастически длинные ресницы: стоило ей смежить и вновь распахнуть
>   веки... http://top-antropos.com/history/20-century/item/223

Хочется думать, что в поиске гипербол за исчерпанием иных анатомических подробностей в устройстве ***глаза*** на этом будет поставлена точка, хотя движение глаз будет всегда самым выразительным и привлекательным в природе человека.

Answer (score 1):

**Это метонимия** (переименование) — вид тропа, связанный  с переносом значения по смежности, в данном случае с предмета на часть предмета. Например: «Все флаги в гости будут к нам», где «флаги» означают «страны»

Answer (score 0):

У меня это выражение на слуху. В Нацкорпусе найдено 6 вхождений *распахнутых ресниц* и 8 *сомкнутых ресниц*.